# ligaçao de uma base de dados mysql a android

Tags: android, mysql

estou à procura de um host gratuito, onde possa guardar a minha base de dados mysql e conecta-la à aplicação android utilizando o programa "Android Studio", podem ajudar?

Comment: Conectar o banco diretamente com o App é o mesmo que deixar a sua conta do banco com a senha `1234`, é totalmente inseguro, com uma simples engenharia reversa, ou até um interceptador de trafego será possivel pegar os dados de autenticação do banco e então você estará totalmente vulnerável, recomendo muito que leia esta pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7763/3635 e esta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50978/3635, elas tem alguns exemplos. Sobre a hospedagem/servidor não posso recomendar nenhum porque não conheço gratuitos que sejam bons, mas creio que tem muitos.

Answer (score 1):

Usa o firebase realtime amigo .

O Firebase Realtime Database é um banco de dados hospedado na nuvem. Os dados são armazenados como JSON e sincronizados em tempo real com todos os clientes conectados. Quando você cria aplicativos multiplataforma com nossos SDKs para iOS, Android e JavaScript, todos os seus clientes compartilham uma instância de Realtime Database e automaticamente recebem atualizações com os dados mais recentes.

fonte : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/?hl=pt-br