# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method group(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, mysql, android, banco-de-dados, android-studio

Oie estou com um problema com um app no Android Studio, ele compila e roda no meu celular, porem quando eu clico em algum botão ele da esse erro.
Erro:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tcc, PID: 11613
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method group(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; in class Ljava/util/regex/Matcher; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.regex.Matcher' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.isConnectionStringSupported(ConnectionUrlParser.java:152)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.acceptsUrl(ConnectionUrl.java:317)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:185)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
    at com.example.tcc.ModelConnection.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:21)
    at com.example.tcc.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

O botão chama um metodo para se conectar ao banco de dados,o banco que estpu usando é o MySQL e estou usando o driver de conexão versão 8.0.21, vou mostra os códigos...

Activity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnConectar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
    android:text="Conectar"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btnCadastrar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnCadastrar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCadastrar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="79dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="229dp"
    android:text="Cadastrar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblCon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:text="Desconectado"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnCadastrar" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtNome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="191dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Nome" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtSenha"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtNome"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtNome"
    tools:text="Senha" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnConectar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConectar);
    ConnectionFactory con = new ConnectionFactory();
    final TextView lblCon = findViewById(R.id.lblCon);

    btnConectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try(Connection con = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                lblCon.setText("Conectado");
            }catch (Exception e){
                lblCon.setText("N foi");
                Log.i(TAG, "onClick: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

ConnectionFactory.java

```
  public ResultSet rs; // Armazenar o resultado
  private String Driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"; // Identificar o banco de dados
  private String caminho = "jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/horarios"; // caminho do bd
private String user = "root"; // usuario para acesso ao bd
private String senha = ""; // senha para acesso ao bd
public Connection conn; // Realiza conexão

public Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName(Driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(caminho, user, senha);// Define a url de conexão
        Log.i(TAG, "Conexão: conectado");
        return conn;
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        return (Connection) ex;
    }
}
```

Vi muitos falando para colocar a activity no manifest, porem ela ja esta lá.
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tcc">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Por favor alguém me ajude, estou fazendo esse app para o meu tcc e a conexão com o mysql tem que ser feita...
Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que o problema é relacionado ao uso do driver de conexão do MySQL.
Nem todas as bibliotecas do Java funcionam no Android.
Sugiro que consulte as seguintes questões relacionadas:
[Como usar MySQL em Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7763/como-usar-mysql-em-android)
e
[Conexão Android com MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50978/conex%C3%A3o-android-com-mysql/50983).